# How to fix Issue with SonarQube report for reactJs project shows error in regular expression

Tags: regex, reactjs, sonarqube

I run sonar scanner on my react js application ,

I got the security Hotspot error for the below code :

```
myString.replace(/^\*|\*$/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Error Desc :

> Using regular expressions is security-sensitive

Do we have any alternative to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure it is an error, not a warning?

Comment: Hi Thanks , is the security Hotspot need to consider as warning or need to work on resolution for that ?